# How to send HTTP 2.0 request in play framework(scala)

Tags: scala, playframework, http2

Backend running under play framework(v. 2.6.5 scala) must communicate with Apple Push Notificaton Service (APNs)  . APNs requires using HTTP/2, and so  i tried to find any way to implement such communication, but to my surprise i didn`t find any http scala clients, supporting http v 2.0.
Is there any way to realize such communication without going out of the framework?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Play Framework with a version prior to 2.6 does not support HTTP 2.0, but, Play Framework 2.6 is based on Akka-Http and has `experimental support` for HTTP 2.0. This feature is labeled "experimental" because the API may change in the future, and it has not been thoroughly tested in the wild.

To add support for HTTP/2, add the `PlayAkkaHttp2Support` plugin. You can do this in an enablePlugins:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .enablePlugins(PlayScala, PlayAkkaHttp2Support)
```

If you consider alternatives take a look at:

1. [`Jetty`](https://webtide.com/introduction-to-http2-in-jetty/) has a capability to use HTTP 2.0
2. [`Netty`](http://netty.io/) also supports HTTP 2.0

Check this [list](https://github.com/http2/http2-spec/wiki/Implementations) of known implementations of HTTP 2.0.

Answer (score 2):

In Akka HTTP, which underlies Play! Framework, HTTP/2 support is experimental on the server side and not yet available on the client side, as far as I can tell. Work is in progress and is tracked on [Github](https://github.com/akka/akka-http/milestone/12). Unless you're inclined to write HTTP/2 client support yourself and optionally donate it to the project (which would probably be a very satisfying experience), going outside of the framework is probably going to be a necessity for now, I'm afraid.

If you're in a position to use Java 9 (hey, it's been gold for two days!), you might consider its HTTP/2 client.

Vert.x is originally a Java framework inspired by NodeJS, but in its current incarnation it includes an HTTP/2 client with a Scala API: http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web-client/scala/ - I've never used it in production so YMMV...

**Edit:** you might also consider [sttp](https://github.com/softwaremill/sttp/blob/master/README.md) with the OkHttp backend, which supports HTTP/2.